# pyspark: write to files after aggregation with reduceByKey

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My code looks like this:

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")
eventRDD = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/python/event16.csv")
outRDDExt = eventRDD.filter(lambda s: "Topic" in s).map(lambda s: s.split('|'))
outRDDExt2 = outRDDExt.keyBy(lambda x: (x[1],x[2][:-19]))
outRDDExt3 = outRDDExt2.mapValues(lambda x: 1)
outRDDExt4 = outRDDExt3.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y)
outRDDExt4.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/python/outDir1")
```

The current output file looks like this:
((u'Topic', u'2017/05/08'), 15)

What I want in my file is this:

u'Topic', u'2017/05/08', 15

How do I get the above output (i.e get rid of the tuples etc from my current output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually expand the tuple and join all elements as string

```
outRDDExt4\
.map(lambda row : ",".join([row[0][1],row[0][1],str(row[1])])\
.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/python/outDir1")
```